# Design vehicle tracking device

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm, atmega328, gps, can-bus

I want to create an Arduino based vehicle tracking device which will be moved into a production board without Arduino later. Right now I have a few questions:

- What GPS module should I use for a best result (little time to fix from a cold start and high accuracy locations)? It will be good if support GLONASS. I want to detect when the car is turning (using HMC5983). I've bought Ublox NEO-6M GPS module and tested it into the car, but it cannot find a location.
- What MCU I should buy? I also want to communicate with OBD II port of vehicle over the CAN protocol (using MCP2551 + MCP2515). For now i choose ATMega328.
- How to power all elements ?

PS: Data from the vehicle and the GPS locations will be send over GPRS with SIM800l module.

Cheers

Comment: This is not on-topic for a good Arduino question.  Generally we want to see a goal, then your attempt to meet that goal, showing parts, photos, code, etc.  Then a very specific question that is also in the title about something that is holding you back from completing the project.  We can't design a project for you.  I highly recommend you read the tour at https://arduino.stackexchange.com/Tour to get the most of this site.  I am voting to keep this open to give you an opportunity to either edit it completely based on what you see in the tour, or delete it yourself.  You are welcome here.

Answer (score 1):

There are some SIMCOM modules with GPRS + GPS, for example: [SIM968](http://www.simcom.eu/index.php?m=termekek&prime=1&sub=41&id=0000000245&page=1)

In addition to GPS, it also supports GLONASS/Galileo/QZSS.

As for the MCU, you will need something more powerful than ATMega328, because 2KB RAM is not enough for multi-threading + GPS code + GSM/GPRS code + CAN + etc. Also it hasn't CAN peripheral. You will need MCU with ARM core. From Arduino line, [Arduino Due](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardDue) looks suitable: has 96KB RAM, multiple HW serials, CAN. There is also compatible CAN library [here](https://github.com/McNeight/CAN_Library). Also worth looking on STM32F103 (or STM32F407 with Cortex M4) which also can used be with Arduino IDE with some extra effort (STM32 MCUs usually more cost effective than Atmel counterparts, and have higher performance).